# How can I run powershell with hidden window?

Tags: powershell, window

I would like to run powershell with a hidden window.

I use this script but the window still appear:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -NoLogo -File "C:\test.ps1"
```

How can I modify the code to run powershell without window?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Start-Process powershell -WindowStyle Hidden
```

You can use the ArgumentList parameter to pass the other parameters like '-File "C:\test.ps1"'